# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/App Name.app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-privateapi

I'm getting an issue upon validating my application saying that I'm accessing a non-public selector `cancelButtonPressed:`. This selector is being called in my static library like this:

```
else if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)])[self.delegate cancelButtonPressed:senderButton];
```

Is this a private method? This didn't cause any issues when I was releasing applications prior to this. Do I need to fix this, or will Apple see that I'm not calling a private method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `cancelButtonPressed:` is an Apple private method. To check just <kbd>option</kbd> click on `cancelButtonPressed` to see it is a public method.
Yes, you will have to stop using it.
Yes, Apple sometimes misses things and catches them later.

Perhaps it is the `@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)` that is at issue instead of calling directly on an instance that is triggering the private method catch by Apple.

Comment: So, I will have to stop using it, even though it's just one of my regular methods I've included in my delegate? Also, is there a list of private methods to overview so I can avoid this hassle in the future? Also, which object does this selector belong to?

Comment: This is a problem and has occurred before. Perhaps it is the `@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)` that is at issue instead of calling directly on an instance that is triggering the private method catch by Apple.

Comment: The option click won't help me, since the method is in my `protocol` declaration. Is there any use to using option click in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the method name conflict with an Apple method name and is causing the problem of false reporting the use of private APIs.

Try changing the method name in your delegate